# What function do I use to call out the complete menu in CVCalendar?

Tags: xcode, swift, func

I am trying to call the entire menu with Month title from Mozharovsky/CVCalendar but I'm not sure what function will call this out? 
This is the current code I am using:

import UIKit
import CVCalendar

class ViewController: UIViewController, CVCalendarViewDelegate, CVCalendarMenuViewDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet weak var calendarView: CVCalendarView!
@IBOutlet weak var menuView: CVCalendarMenuView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar 

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    calendarView.commitCalendarViewUpdate()
    menuView.commitMenuViewUpdate()
}


func presentationMode() -> CalendarMode {
    return CalendarMode.MonthView
}

func firstWeekday() -> Weekday {
    return Weekday.Sunday
}
```

}

This is the what is rendered when compiled:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the month title also you need to create a UIlabel and UIlabel outlet as such:
    @IBOutlet weak var monthLabel: UILabel!

I got this answer by copying the code from Mozharovsky/CVCalendar Demo ViewController.swift file